# Crystal Report Date formula to make it the end of the month

Tags: date, crystal-reports, formula

I'm new to CR and need a formula that would give me the end of the month a on a date field.
If the Date is 628/2012 or 7/12/2012 I need the formula to to be the end of the month no matter which day of the month the field shows. Of course we know that not every month ends on the 30th or 31th and February sometimes 29th or 30th. So what formula can I use to do this

Example field name {table.end_date}

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a formula field to calculate the end of the month:

```
//{@EndOfMonth}
// find the first day of the month, add a month to it, then subtract a day
DateAdd("m", 1, DateTime( Year({table.dateField}), Month({table.dateField}), 1, 0,0,0 )) - 1
```

Create a second formula that will generate a textual representation:

```
//{@TextRepresentation}
If Isnull({table.end_date}) Then
  Space(8)
Else
  ToText({@EndOfMonth}, "YYYYMMDD")
```

Comment: So I tried it but keep getting a boolean error with the rest of the formula I'm trying to add to it. if totext({table,end_date}) <> " "
then totext ({table,end_date},"MMddyyyy") 
else totext ("        ") 
and 
DateAdd("m", 1, DateTime( Year({table,end_date}),
 Month({table,end_date}), 1, 0,0,0 )) – 1       What do you think it could be causing the error or am I going to wrong way on this. Again thanks for your help

Comment: Is `end_date` a `DATE` field?  Why are you trying to convert it to a single space?

Comment: Yes the end date is a DATE field and I'm converting it to a 8 space character if there is not date in the field to hold 8 spaces for a text export I'm doing with the report

Comment: I try to avoid exporting RPTs to anything other than PDF.  CSV and TTX should keep the placeholder for a NULL value in a field.  What are you using?

Comment: That worked thanks for your help. Its a export to a .txt file to be uploaded to another site. I'm using the export function in crystal to do this. Again thanks for your help.