# Crystal report find the last month end date

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal report, I want to find the last month end date if I give any date

I searched and got this : [Crystal Report Date formula to make it the end of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837372/crystal-report-date-formula-to-make-it-the-end-of-the-month) but nothing more specific to my query

eg:

```
Suppose if I give date as : 21/06/2013  
formula: formula{?date}  
expected output : 31/05/2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a formula and use the following code

```
CDATE(DATEADD("d", -1, DATE(YEAR({?Parameter}), MONTH({?Parameter}), 1)))
```

the parameter must be of date type.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula:

```
DateAdd ("d", -DatePart ("d", {?Parameter}), {?Parameter})
```