# Is there a quick and easy way to print the end of the month date on a crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am building a really simple report in Crystal Reports and we need it to print the last day of the month, based off the month it is being printed in.

I would assume that Crystal has some way of doing this due to the "Special fields" like Print Date. Or am I going to have to write an if-then-else?

Comment: See here:  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837372/crystal-report-date-formula-to-make-it-the-end-of-the-month

Comment: Thanks! With some alteration I got that to work for me.

Comment: @AliciaUhacz you can answer your question so that others can use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way you can get the end of the month printed in your report is using this formula

```
dateserial(year(currentdate),month(currentdate)+1,1-1)
```

it will give you last day of current month, if you need a month before just subtract 1 in this part of the code `month(currentdate)+1` and for a month after add 1 instead and so on and so forth

Comment: The only problem I'm running into with this, is that it's printing 2 months prior as opposed to 1 month prior. So, we are in August and it prints June.

Comment: July: dateserial(year(currentdate),month(currentdate),1-1)

Answer (score 1):

I used the formula discuss here: [Crystal Report Date formula to make it the end of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837372/crystal-report-date-formula-to-make-it-the-end-of-the-month) and that worked for me with some alteration. I changed it to suit my purposes as follows:

```
//{@EndOfMonth} // find the first day of the month, add a month to it, then subtract a day DateAdd("m", 1, DateTime( Year(CurrentDate), Month(CurrentDate), 1, 0,0,0 )) - 1 –
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
CDate(DateAdd("d", -1, DateSerial(Year(CurrentDate), Month(CurrentDate) + 1, 1)))
```

Comment: I created a formula (EndOfMonth) that looks like this: //{@EndOfMonth}
// find the first day of the month, add a month to it, then subtract a day
DateAdd("m", 1, DateTime( Year(CurrentDate), Month(CurrentDate), 1, 0,0,0 )) - 1

Comment: @KristoferA I have tested the solution and it works irrespective of month report is picking... Can you add your comments where this soltion fails?

Comment: @Siva You're right: apparently the VBA DateSerial can do rollovers for invalid dates, and accepts a month value of 13... I had expected it to fail.